# Suppose a matrix valued function $A$ with $A(0) = I$, find $\frac{d^2}{dt^2} det(A(t)) $ at $t=0$

Tags: matrices, derivatives

The original question is : Let $A(t)$ be a differentiable square matrix valued function with
$A(0) = I$, find $\frac{d^2}{dt^2} det(A(t)) $ at $t=0$ in term of $\dot{A}$ and $\ddot{A}$.

I know in the first derivative case for $A(0)=I$, we have $\frac{d}{dt} det A(t) \big|_{t=0}= tr \dot {A}(0)$ from a textbook.

Hence here is what I think, since $\frac{d}{dt} det A(t) \big|_{t=0}= tr \dot {A}(0)$, then $\frac{d}{dt}\frac{d}{dt} det A(t) \big|_{t=0}= \frac{d}{dt}tr \dot {A}(0)= tr \frac{d}{dt} \dot {A}(0)=tr \ddot {A}(0)$.

Am I right? I am not sure about this. Please help, thanks a lot!

Comment: No you are wrong. To find $A''(0)$ you need to compute $A'(t)$ for $t$ small, not only $A'(0)$. Another method is to develop $A(t)$ at the second order around $0$ (if you already have an argument to explain that $A$ is twice differentiable)

Comment: @JohnSteinbeck Thank you! can yo give a bit more hint? how to compute $A'(t)$ for $t$ small?

Comment: if u know the identiy $\det(A)=\exp(\text{tr}\log(A))$ it might be quiet useful

Comment: It is classical that
$$\det'(A)(H)=tr(com(A)^TH)$$
I believe it is easy to prove if you know $A$ is inversible and if you already know (which you do) $\det'(I)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f:t\rightarrow \det(A(t))$. Then $f'(t)=tr(adj(A)A')$ and $f''(t)=tr((adj(A))'A')+tr(adj(A)A'')$. It remains to calculate  $g'(t)$ where $g(t)=adj(A)=\det(A)A^{-1}=f(t)A^{-1}$.

Thus $g'(t)=tr(adj(A)A')A^{-1}-\det(A)A^{-1}A'A^{-1}$ and we are done.

Note that, when $t=0$, $A^{-1}=adj(A)=I,\det(A)=1$.